# Routing to a different channels based on condition

Tags: spring-integration

I would like to route the message to different channels based on the condition of the property.
Let's say I have score property. If the score is <100 then it goes to "perfectchannel" else it goes to "normalchannel"

Where do I specify the spel expression or condition

```
<si:router id="serviceRouter" input-channel="serviceRoutingChannel"
    expression="payload.score" default-output-channel="badchannel"
    resolution-required="false">
    <si:mapping value="100" channel="perfectchannel" />
    <si:mapping value="<100 ??" channel="normalchannel" />
</si:router>
```

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 2):

We have a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2808) on the matter, but haven't come up with the solution yet.

Right now you can achieve this behaviour with condition from the `expression` and providing mapping for `true` and `false` and with cascad of the routers:

```
<si:router id="serviceRouter" input-channel="serviceRoutingChannel"
    expression="payload.score == 100">
    <si:mapping value="true" channel="perfectChannel" />
    <si:mapping value="false" channel="nestedRouterChannel" />
</si:router>

<si:router input-channel="nestedRouterChannel"
    expression="payload.score lt 100">
    <si:mapping value="true" channel="normalChannel" />
    <si:mapping value="false" channel="badChannel" />
</si:router>
```

**UPDATE**

Another option to use `<recipient-list-router>`:

```
<recipient-list-router id="serviceRouter" input-channel="serviceRoutingChannel">
    <recipient selector-expression="payload.score == 100" channel="perfectchannel"/>
    <recipient selector-expression="payload.score lt 100" channel="normalchannel"/>
    <recipient selector-expression="payload.score gt 100" channel="badchannel"/>
</recipient-list-router>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I like the option of <recipient-list-router instead of nested routing. I will try that.