# Conditional Transformer Routing based on enviroment property in spring integration xml

Tags: java, xml, spring-integration, transformer-model

I am using spring-integration , i have a requirement that based on system environment variable i want to switch message to either of the transformer.

I tried with the question answered here :[Condition recipient-list-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393767/routing-to-a-different-channels-based-on-condition)
but as recipient-list-router solution would be only applicable if i want to direct to different channels but here the problem is that the channel configured for both the transformers is **same** also both transformers have **same input channel** only based on environment property i want to route them to **different output channel**.
Like

```
<int:transformer id="messageTransformer" ref="messageTransformerBean" 
    input-channel="validMessageChannel" method="transform" output-channel="Channel-A" 
    />
```

so if environement variable is true then output this transformed message to channel-A otherwise to channel-B

```
<int:transformer id="messageTransformer" ref="messageTransformerBean"
    input-channel="validMessageChannel" method="transform" output-channel="Channel -B" />
```

Is there any way to achieve this ,please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Change the output channels of both transformers to `routingChannel` then add a router that has `routingChannel` for its `input-channel` and routes to `channel-A` or `-B` depending on your condition.