# Spring integration router with condition

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have a header witch is incremented during flow, than message goes to a loop, where I route it based on this header value. I cant find a way to config this router.

I found this question
[Routing to a different channels based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393767/routing-to-a-different-channels-based-on-condition)

but it uses payload instead of headers: <expression="payload.score == 100">

I tried using Java config like this:

```
public ExpressionEvaluatingRouter router() {
        var router = new ExpressionEvaluatingRouter("payload.getHeaders().get(failCount) => 2");
        router.setChannelMapping("true", "logFailedChannel");
        router.setChannelMapping("false", "retryChannel");
        return router;
    }
```

But it fails as it can not parse this "payload.getHeaders().get(failCount) => 5"

I also tried using HeaderRouner, but it wasn't good for me, because I had to hardcode every option for my conditions like this:

```
router.setChannelMapping("1", "retryChannel");
router.setChannelMapping("2", "retryChannel");
router.setChannelMapping("3", "logFailedChannel");
router.setChannelMapping("4", "logFailedChannel");
```

etc.

Is there any other way to config router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`payload.getHeaders().get(failCount) => 2`

There is no such method `getHeaders()` (unless your payload has one). The root for evaluation is `Message<?>` which has `payload` and `headers` properties.

Try `headers.get('failCount') >= 2`.